# Unable to connect to JIRA project with API Auth Token in Python

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, python-requests, jira, jira-rest-api

Trying to connect to JIRA project using python code

```
r = requests.get('https://myproject.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project="myprojectid"', auth=('myuser@mydomain.com', 'Basic abcdefghijabcdefghij='))

print(r.headers)
```

And I am getting following error

```
{'Server': 'AtlassianProxy/1.15.8.1', 'WWW-Authenticate': 'OAuth realm="https%3A%2F%2Fmyproject.atlassian.net"', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=315360000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'Date': 'Fri, 08 Nov 2019 07:59:26 GMT', 'ATL-TraceId': 'aaaaaaaaaaaa', 'X-AREQUESTID': '000000-0000-0000-0000-0000', 'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Timing-Allow-Origin': '*', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Seraph-LoginReason': 'AUTHENTICATED_FAILED'}
```

where as when I do curl using same auth token I am able to access the projects

```
$ curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic abcdefghijabcdefghij=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://myproject.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=myprojectid"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script instead of using base64 of your email address and API token like this

'''
"Basic abcdefghijabcdefghij="
'''

just use your email address and api token and the above code would be

'''
r = requests.get('https://myproject.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project="myprojectid"', auth=('myuser@mydomain.com', 'xyzzzzzzz'))

'''